# Adding css while in controller

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to load a css name into a session variable and then have it load a css on the _Layout.cshtml.

This is what I attempted to do:

```
  var companycss = string.Format("~/Content/CompanyFiles/{0}/{0}.css", MySession.CssName);

  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/site.css",
    "~/Content/justified-nav.css",
    "~/Content/Styles.css",
    companycss)); // <-- Custom CSS file
```

The BundleConfig.cs apparently loads before my index method in my HomeController so it is not loading this style sheet.

In my Index method, I am loading the MySession.CssName and was hoping for it to load correctly in to the page since I am deciding which css to load when the customer visits the site.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you create a static bundle for each company, it's going to be pretty much impossible to achieve what you want here. In other words, you can't rely on the session in BundleConfig.cs, but you *could* reference a different bundle in your layout via a session variable. The bundle would just have to have been already defined.

Alternatively, if you don't mind loading two bundles, you can dynamically create a bundle in the view. You'd essentially just make your `~/Content/css` bundle include all the CSS except the company CSS file. Then you could do something like:

```
@{ BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle(String.Format("~/bundles/{0}", MySession.CssName)).Include(String.Format("~/Content/CompanyFiles/{0}/{0}.css", MySession.CssName))); }
@Styles.Render(String.Format("~/bundles/{0}", MySession.CssName))
```

This will add a new bundle for this specific company's CSS and then load it. You'll end up then with two stylesheets loaded, instead of just one, but they'll both be minified.

**EDIT**

I've never considered this before, but you might be able to combine the code from your BundleConfig.cs with this latter option and achieve a single bundle. However, you're essentially shifting code out of `BundleConfig.cs` and into your layout. Some might consider that a faux pas, and it does certainly trample on the principles of the MVC pattern. Still, for completeness:

```
@{
    var companycss = string.Format("~/Content/CompanyFiles/{0}/{0}.css", MySession.CssName);

    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
        "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
        "~/Content/site.css",
        "~/Content/justified-nav.css",
        "~/Content/Styles.css",
        companycss)); // <-- Custom CSS file
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but I was coming back to delete this. I went another way. I added it to the `_layout.cshtml` under  `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` which seems to work.

Comment: Yes. The key is simply that you need to utilize the session variable some place where it's actually available, i.e. *not* BundleConfig.cs.